# Checking if a function is injective

Tags: functions, category-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a small category, whose objects are thought of as "admissible worlds" and whose arrows as "temporal admissible developments". Let $X:\mathbb{C}^{\operatorname{op}}\rightarrow \operatorname{Sets}$ be a presheaf of sets defined on $\mathbb{C}$. Denote by $\sigma X$ the image of the world $\sigma$ via the functor $X$. An element $s\in\sigma X$ is called "a person" of $X$, living in the world $\sigma$.

For every admissible temporal development $\pi:\rho\rightarrow\sigma$, denote by $\pi X:\rho X\gets\sigma X$ the image of $\pi$ via $X$, which is a function that associates to each person $s\in\sigma X$, living in $\sigma$, a person $\pi s\in\rho X$, living in $\rho$ ($\pi s$ is short notation for $(\pi X)(s)$).

We'll think of $\pi s$ as the ancestor of $s$, with respect to the past temporal development $\pi:\rho\rightarrow \sigma$.

To each person $s\in\sigma X$ we associate the whole family of ancestors of $s$, denoted by
$$ (-)\cdot s=\{\pi s\}_{\rho;\pi:\rho\rightarrow\sigma}$$
indexed by the set of arrows of $\mathbb{C}$, having codomain $\sigma$, the world where $s$ lives.

I wish that this function were injective, meaning that

$$(-)\cdot s=(-)\cdot s'\Rightarrow s=s'$$
but i can't prove it. Could someone help me?

Comment: I'm curious to know where you found this categorical interpretation. Something online?

Comment: @rschwieb from mathematical logic lecture notes of my university

Comment: I do not fully understand the notation for the family of ancestors: $\pi s$ is an element of the set $\rho X:=X(\rho)$, am I right?

Comment: @Avitus Yes, you are right

Comment: Ok, then you fix an $s$ from the very beginning and the family of ancestors of $s$ is obtained by considering all possible admissible maps $\pi$ into the world $s$ lives in. At first glance I would add the condition that $s$ and $s'$ must live in the same world before addressing the problem of injectivity

Comment: I think that injectivity fails because in the real world one have brothers and sisters...

Comment: @Avitus I suppose that in this contest the notion of past is to be understood in a broad sense: past:=past+present. Hence, given two brothers $A$ and $B$, $A$ has himself as ancestor, but $A$ is not an ancestor of $B$, so that $A$ and $B$ have not the same set of ancestors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you excuse me if I will use more standard notation.

Let $\sigma\in\mathbb{C}$, $s,s'\in X(\sigma)$, we have to prove, that if $s\ne s'$, then $(-)\cdot s\ne(-)\cdot s'$. Actually, $(-)\cdot s$ is a mapping $Ob(\mathbb{C}\downarrow\sigma)\to\bigcup_{c\in\mathbb{C}}X(c)$.

Let $s\ne s'$. Then, we have to prove, that there exists such $p\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\pi\colon p\to\sigma$, such that $((-)\cdot s)(\pi)\ne((-)\cdot s')(\pi)$. Put $p=\sigma$ and $\pi=id(\sigma)$. Then we have $((-)\cdot s)(id(\sigma))=id(X(\sigma))(s)=s$ and $((-)\cdot s')(id(\sigma))=id(X(\sigma))(s')=s'$, but they are not equal, QED.

Comment: Could you add some details? I can't understand your proof. Identity arrow is not the only arrow from $\sigma$ to $\sigma$

Comment: @Federica OK, I will try.

Comment: @Federica If "being an ancestor of a fixed $s$" is a property defined in the past and in the present, then different $s$'s cannot have the same family of ancestors: this is because $s$ belongs to $\{\pi s\}$ but not $s'$, and viceversa: as Oskar pointed out, in the above setting (past+present) the identity map is an admissible temporal development.